# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In this part code show this error: `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

```
  contrat: Contrat[];
  gpss: GPS[];
  homeboxp: HomeboxP[];
  sensors: Sensors[];
  homebox: Homebox[];

  getProductName(productid: string) {
    const [filteredProd] = this.contrat.filter(pt => pt.contrat_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdG] = this.gpss.filter(pt => pt.gps_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdhbp] = this.homeboxp.filter(pt => pt.homeboxpackage_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdh] = this.homebox.filter(pt => pt.homebox_id === productid);
    const [filteredProds] = this.sensors.filter(pt => pt.sensors_id === productid);

    if (typeof filteredProd !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProd.contrat_id) {
      return filteredProd.contratdesc;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdG !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdG.gps_id) {
      return filteredProdG.gps_serial;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdhbp !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdhbp.homeboxpackage_id) {
      return filteredProdhbp.serial_number;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdh !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdh.homebox_id) {
      return filteredProdh.serial_number;
    } else if (typeof filteredProds !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProds.sensors_id) {
      return filteredProds.sensor_serial;
    }
  }
```

Can you sugest me, what is the problem in this part? Work very good, but show this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that `this.contract` , `this.gpss`, `this.homeboxp`, `this.homebox` or `this.sensors` are defined before you call the method?

Comment: Can you show these definitions that @Safiyya mentioned?

Comment: @Safiyya Yes, contrat: Contrat[];  gpss: GPS[];  homeboxp: HomeboxP[];  sensors: Sensors[];  homebox: Homebox[];

Comment: Well your arrays have no content, and also are `undefined`, so what are you expected to filter?

Comment: @Alex,  you are right. I solve this error. Thnak you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initiatize your arrays before you use them :

```
  contrat: Contrat[] = [];
  gpss: GPS[] = [];
  homeboxp: HomeboxP[] = [];
  sensors: Sensors[] = [];
  homebox: Homebox[] =[];
```

Comment: Could you add a `console.log(this.contract, this.gpss, this.homeboxp, this.sensors, this.homebox)` at the top of your method and share the results?

Comment: It's okej. Thank you :)